# Javascript: Is reassigning a function parameter to a temporary variable sufficient?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

With flow, there's the option `experimental.const_params=true` which [treats function parameters as const bindings](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-experimental-const-params-boolean). I can easily make the error go away by assigning it to a temporary variable, but does that actually address the bad form of reassigning/mutating a function parameter?

For example:

```
function someFunc(p1) {
  let temp = p1;
  temp.x = 10
  return temp
}
```

As opposed to:

```
function someFunc(p1) {
  p1.x = 10
  return p1
}
```

For flow, that is sufficient to keep flow from throwing an error.

Does it actually address what that rule is attempting to address? If not what should be used instead?

Comment: I would say that the option is to ensure the parameters are not modified, so by reassigning it you're just skirting around the rule.

Comment: The rule aims to reduce side-effects, in this case, the function modifying its inputs. Regardless of how you do it, you're currently simply sidestepping its point. If you don't want to follow that practice, I would suggest turning the rule off altogether.

Comment: But what's the correct form then? According to this it's correct, but I agree it just seems like sidestepping https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

Comment: There's a link at the end of the eslint doc page you linked to that explains why such a rule exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with whats being passed.  In your example, p1 is an object, so the parameter is an object reference.  The members of the object are not protected by the 'const' type.  You might want to look at Object.freeze() if you want to prevent objects from being mutated.